# Delete rows of a column using another column statistics in R

Tags: r, dataset, data-cleaning

I have a dataframe with the following columns:

[image]

If a year (see "year" column) has less than 10 weeks reported, I would like to delete it from the dataframe. The column "weeks_reporting" gives the order of the week in a year. How can I accomplish this task in R?

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this using a logic index as follows:

```
us_contagious_diseases<-us_contagious_diseases[!(us_contagious_diseases$weeks_reporting<"10"),]
```

Answer (score 1):

you can accomplish in multiple ways, eg with with `dplyr`:

```
 library(dplyr)
 us_contagious_diseases %>%
   filter(weeks_reporting >= 10)
```